# Page contents jump slightly horizontally when navigating between similar pages

Tags: html, css

When I navigate between the following two pages (page1.html and page2.html) the page contents jump horizontally slightly. Going from page1.html to page2.html, the contents jump slightly to the left. In the other direction, the contents jump slightly to the right. Both pages use the same css file (styles.css). I'm using Chrome on an iMac. The screenshot below is of page1.html. The file page2.html is similar but with one more entry (each entry is an image with a caption, sound and example sentences). There is a link, in the comments, to page1.html in a test directory on my website. If you click on "Next Page" on page1.html it will take you to page2.html. Clicking on "Previous Page" on page2.html will take you back to page1.html. Do you know what could be causing the problem?
[image: page1.html]

```
<!-- page1.html --> 

<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Main Title</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<h1>Main Title</h1>
<nav id = "navbar">
<div class="navoption">
<a href="option1.html" class="currentpage">Option 1</a>
</div>
<div class="navoption">
<a href="option2.html">Option 2</a>
</div>
<div class="navoption">
<a href="option3.html">Option 3</a>
</div>
<div class="navoption" id="moremenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickMoreMenu()">More...</a>
<div id="hiddenlinks">
<a href="option4.html">Option 4</a>
<a href="option5.html">Option 5</a>
<a href="option6.html">Option 6</a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="clearfloats"></div>
<h2>Topic: Page 1 of 9
</h2>
<div class="listofentries">
<hr>
<div class="dictionaryentry">
<div class="imagewithcaption">
<img src="image1.jpg" class="dictionaryimage"/>
<div class="englishword">caption 1</div>
</div>
<div class="spanishwordwithaudio">
<span class="spanishwordelabourated">
<span class="spanishword">palabra</span>
<span class="spanishgenderpost">(m/f)</span>
</span>
<audio class = spanishaudio controls>
<source src = "palabra1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src = "palabra1.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>
<h4 class="examplesentenceheading">Example Sentence:</h4>
<div class="englishsentence">A sentence.</div>
<div class="spanishsentence">A sentence.</div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<nav class="previousandnextpage">
<a href="page0.html">Previous Page</a><a href="page2.html">Next Page</a>
</nav>
<div class="backtoindex"> <a href="index.html">Back to Index</a> </div>
<div class="copyright">Copyright blah.</div>
</div>
<script src="moremenu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- page2.html -->
  
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Main Title</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<h1>Main Title</h1>
<nav id = "navbar">
<div class="navoption">
<a href="option1.html" class="currentpage">Option 1</a>
</div>
<div class="navoption">
<a href="option2.html">Option 2</a>
</div>
<div class="navoption">
<a href="option3.html">Option 3</a>
</div>
<div class="navoption" id="moremenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickMoreMenu()">More...</a>
<div id="hiddenlinks">
<a href="option4.html">Option 4</a>
<a href="option5.html">Option 5</a>
<a href="option6.html">Option 6</a>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="clearfloats"></div>
<h2>Topic: Page 2 of 9
</h2>
<div class="listofentries">
<hr>
<div class="dictionaryentry">
<div class="imagewithcaption">
<img src="image1.jpg" class="dictionaryimage"/>
<div class="englishword">caption 1</div>
</div>
<div class="spanishwordwithaudio">
<span class="spanishwordelabourated">
<span class="spanishword">palabra</span>
<span class="spanishgenderpost">(m/f)</span>
</span>
<audio class = spanishaudio controls>
<source src = "palabra2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src = "palabra2.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>
<h4 class="examplesentenceheading">Example Sentence:</h4>
<div class="englishsentence">A sentence.</div>
<div class="spanishsentence">A sentence.</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="dictionaryentry">
<div class="imagewithcaption">
<img src="image2.jpg" class="dictionaryimage"/>
<div class="englishword">caption 2</div>
</div>
<div class="spanishwordwithaudio">
<span class="spanishwordelabourated">
<span class="spanishword">palabra</span>
<span class="spanishgenderpost">(m)</span>
</span>
<audio class = spanishaudio controls>
<source src = "palabra3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src = "palabra3.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>
<div class="spanishwordwithaudio">
<span class="spanishwordelabourated">
<span class="spanishword">palabra</span>
<span class="spanishgenderpost">(f)</span>
</span>
<audio class = spanishaudio controls>
<source src = "palabra4.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src = "palabra4.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>
<h4 class="examplesentenceheading">Example Sentence:</h4>
<div class="englishsentence">A sentence.</div>
<div class="spanishsentence">A sentence.</div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<nav class="previousandnextpage">
<a href="page1.html">Previous Page</a><a href="page3.html">Next Page</a>
</nav>
<div class="backtoindex"> <a href="index.html">Back to Index</a> </div>
<div class="copyright">Copyright blah.</div>
</div>
<script src="moremenu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* ----- CSS Starts Here ----- */ 

#page {
    width : 500px; 
    margin-left : auto; 
    margin-right : auto; 
} 


#navbar { 
    padding : 0; 
    display : block;   
    width : 404px; 
    margin-left : auto;  
    margin-right : auto; 
} 

.navoption {
   text-align : center; 
   display : block; 
   float : left; 
}  

#moremenu {
    display : block; 
}


#hiddenlinks {
    display: none;
    position : absolute; 
    z-index : 1;
    background : white; 
}


#navbar a { 
    display : block; 
    text-align : center; 
    text-decoration : none; 
    padding-top : 10px;  
    padding-bottom : 10px; 
    width : 100px; 
    color : blue; 
    background : yellow; 
    border-style : solid; 
    border-color : blue;  
    border-width : 1px; 
    margin-bottom : 1px; 
    margin-right : 1px;
    box-sizing : border-box; 
    border-collapse : collapse; 
} 



#navbar a.currentpage { 
    background : blue; 
    color : yellow; 
    border-color : yellow; 
} 


#navbar a:hover { 
    background : LightPink; 
    color : Indigo; 
    border-color : Indigo; 
} 


.clearfloats { 
    clear :  left; 
} 


h1 { 
    color : blue; 
    text-align : center; 
} 


h2 { 
    color : Blue; 
    text-align : center; 
    margin-top : 20px; 
} 


.englishword { 
    color : black; 
    font-weight : bold;  
    text-align : center; 
    font-size : large; 
} 


.englishwordmodifier { 
    color : black; 
    text-align : center; 
} 


.imagewithcaption {
    width : 125px; 
    margin-bottom : 15px; 
}


.dictionaryimage {
    display : block; 
    margin-left : auto; 
    margin-right : auto; 
    margin-bottom : 5px; 
} 


.spanishgenderpost { 
    font-family : monospace; 
} 

.spanishword { 
    color : blue; 
    font-weight : bold; 
} 


.spanishwordelabourated { 
    display : inline-block; 
}


.spanishwordwithaudio { 
    margin-top : 7px; 
    margin-bottom : 7px; 
} 

.spanishaudio { 
     vertical-align : middle;  
     width : 220px; 
}


h4.examplesentenceheading { 
    text-decoration : underline;  
    margin-top : 5px; 
    margin-bottom : 2px; 
} 


.spanishsentence { 
    color : blue; 
} 

.englishsentence { 
    color : black; 
} 

.highlightword { 
    font-weight : bold; 
    font-style : italic; 
} 


.listofentries { 
    width : 500px; 
    margin-left : auto; 
    margin-right : auto; 
    margin-bottom : 10px; 
} 


.dictionaryentry { 
    margin-top : 15px; 
    margin-bottom : 15px; 
} 

.sentencenote { 
    font-style : italic; 
} 

.backtoindex, 
.previousandnextpage {
    display : block; 
    padding-top : 10px; 
    padding-bottom : 10px; 
    text-align : center; 
} 

.backtoindex a, 
.previousandnextpage a { 
    display : inline-block; 
    color : red; 
    text-decoration : none; 
    text-align : center; 
    width : 125px; 
    padding-top : 5px; 
    padding-bottom : 5px; 
    border-style : solid;  
    border-width : 1px; 
    border-color : blue; 
    box-sizing : border-box; 
    margin-right : 1px; 
} 


.copyright { 
    text-align : center; 
    margin-top : 15px; 
    font-size : small; 
} 

/* ----- CSS Ends Here ----- */
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce from what you've put in the question.  Pasted into 3 files and used next and previous buttons in chrome, IE and edge and there was no shifting.

Comment: Thanks for trying @JustinNimmo, I'm not sure what went wrong there. I've now added new files, hopefully these will show the problem.

Comment: Sorry, still no issue.

Comment: @JustinNimmo That's strange, for me it is definitely shifting. Is it possible that the problem is related to the images? I'm assuming you might be not have used images when you checked.

Comment: @JustinNimmo I just deleted the images and checked again, there was no shift.

Comment: @JustinNimmo I've uploaded page1.html, page2.html, styles.css and the images to a test directory on my website. page1.html can be accessed [here](http://learnspanishvocabulary.net/test/page1.html)